# Plot Only to Portion of Barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

How can I plot only the top portion of a barplot so as to emphasize the difference between the bars without manually calculating the differences and plotting these. I care about the actual values and would thus prefer if these were on the y-axis. It seems like there should be an easy way to accomplish this. If not, I can plot differences and manually change the values which appear on the y-axis.

By changing the ylim I can display the portions of the barplot that have variation, like I want, but part of the bars go through my margins.

```
barplot(c(54.0, 56.7, 55.9, 59.0), ylim=c(50,60))
```

The original, less informative plot:

```
barplot(c(54.0, 56.7, 55.9, 59.0))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did my answer give you the expected result? If so, please consider accepting it, otherwise, please provide some further info so that we can improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try xpd = FALSE in your call:

```
barplot(c(54.0, 56.7, 55.9, 59.0), ylim=c(50,60), xpd = FALSE)
box() #maybe nicer if you add this too
```

HTH